# Not able to white list h2-console url in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am not able to access /h2-console with spring secutity enabled.

Below is the config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console()))
                .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .addFilterBefore(new ProductFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

    }
}
```

I tried multiple option suggested in stack overflow but seems not working.

Comment: Do you added the `DataSource` configuration in the H2 configs?

Comment: @DiegoBorba Yes I did...application is working fine and also able to persist data. But only problem when I am trying to view the data using h2-console.

Comment: If you will replace `requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()` to `requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()`  is it will work ?

Comment: and also remove this line of code `csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console()))` because you are disabling it at all on next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to expose a separate `SecurityFilterChain` for the H2 Console that looks like this:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityFilterChain h2ConsoleSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(PathRequest.toH2Console());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(yourCustomAuthorization());
    http.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
    http.headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions((frame) -> frame.sameOrigin()));
    return http.build();
}
```

There is more information on this in the reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.h2-web-console.spring-security